# RegExp to match whole word contained in expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string expression:

```
let expression = "MAX_NUM_OF_LOOKUP_GROUPS/NUM_OF_LOOKUP_GROUPS"
```

I need to assign values instead of the strings NUM_OF_LOOKUP_GROUPS and MAX_NUM_OF_LOOKUP_GROUPS.
I have the following RegExp that tries to do that with no success:

```
expression = expression.replace(new RegExp("(^|\\W)NUM_OF_LOOKUP_GROUPS($|\\W)", 'g'), 4)
// expression now equals to MAX_4
```

I need expression to be equaled to MAX_NUM_OF_LOOKUP_GROUPS/4.

The RegExp should also be able to replace the string MAX_NUM_OF_LOOKUP_GROUPS as well.
Thanks!

Comment: Use: `expression = expression.replace(/\bNUM_OF_LOOKUP_GROUPS\b/, '4')`

Comment: If your expected output is `MAX_NUM_OF_LOOKUP_GROUPS/4` then how is this true: `The RegExp should also be able to replace the string MAX_NUM_OF_LOOKUP_GROUPS as well.`

Comment: I meant when doing this: ```expression = expression.replace(new RegExp("(^|\\W)MAX_NUM_OF_LOOKUP_GROUPS($|\\W)", 'g'), 4)```

Answer (score 0):

```
expression = "MAX_NUM_OF_LOOKUP_GROUPS/NUM_OF_LOOKUP_GROUPS"
values = [17, 29]
expression.replace(/\bMAX_NUM_OF_LOOKUP_GROUPS\b/, values[0])
          .replace(/\bNUM_OF_LOOKUP_GROUPS\b/, values[1])
// "17/29"
```